# I run Micromouse simulation (mms by Mackorone) using BFS algorithm but it not going well

Tags: algorithm, simulation

When I run simulation the mouse (the simulate I use it make by Mackorone) did mark the wall I sure about that but after every loop the maze still not update. First I think the mouse not update the wall after mark it but when I log out it did mark wall. Then I check did the flood fill work so every loop flood fill didn't update wall so the mouse keep spinning around after few wall past. But when I mark wall by hand it works fine.

I want ever loop algorithm update the maze. Here is my source code and simulation:(https://github.com/mackorone/mms)
(https://github.com/kinhkong69z/KhoeMach-Micromouse)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>

#include "API.h"

std::pair<int, int> west_wall[1000];
std::pair<int, int> east_wall[1000];
std::pair<int, int> north_wall[1000];
std::pair<int, int> south_wall[1000];
int w = 0, e = 0, n = 0, s = 0;
std::string direct_mouse[5];
std::string wall_l, wall_r, wall_f;

void log(const std::string& text) {
std::cerr << text << std::endl;
}
void mark_wall(int mx, int my, std::string &direct){
if(direct == "w"){
    west_wall[w].first = mx;
    west_wall[w].second = my;
    w++;
}
else if(direct == "e"){
    east_wall[e].first = mx;
    east_wall[e].second = my;
    e++;
}
else if(direct == "n"){
    north_wall[n].first = mx;
    north_wall[n].second = my;
    n++;
}
else if(direct == "s"){
    south_wall[s].first = mx;
    south_wall[s].second = my;
    s++;
}
}


bool check_wall(int mx, int my, std::string direct){
int k = 0;
if(direct == "w"){
    for(int i = 0; i < w; i++)
        if(west_wall[i].first == mx && west_wall[i].second == my)
            k++;
}
else if(direct == "e"){
    for(int i = 0; i < e; i++)
        if(east_wall[i].first == mx && east_wall[i].second == my){
            k++;
        }
            
}
else if(direct == "n"){
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if(north_wall[i].first == mx && north_wall[i].second == my)
            k++;
}
else if(direct == "s"){
    for(int i = 0; i < s; i++)
        if(south_wall[i].first == mx && south_wall[i].second == my)
            k++;
}
if(k == 0)
    return false;
else
    return true;
}
void mouse_way(int d){

direct_mouse[1] = "n";
direct_mouse[2] = "e";
direct_mouse[3] = "s";
direct_mouse[4] = "w";

if(d == 1)
{
    wall_f = "n";
    wall_l = "w";
    wall_r = "e";
}
else if(d == 2){
    wall_f = "e";
    wall_l = "n";
    wall_r = "s";
}
else if(d == 3){
    wall_f = "s";
    wall_l = "e";
    wall_r = "w";
}
else if(d == 4){
    wall_f = "w";
    wall_l = "s";
    wall_r = "n";
}
}



void bfs(std::vector<std::vector<int>>& maze, int mx, int my){
std::queue<std::pair<int, int>> q;
//base case

if(!check_wall(mx - 1, my, "s")){
    maze[mx - 1][my] = 1;q.push({mx - 1, my});
}
if(!check_wall(mx - 1, my + 1, "s")){
    maze[mx - 1][my + 1] = 1;q.push({mx - 1, my + 1});
}
if(!check_wall(mx, my + 2, "w")){
    maze[mx][my + 2] = 1;q.push({mx, my + 2});
}
if(!check_wall(mx + 1, my + 2, "w")){
    maze[mx + 1][my + 2] = 1;q.push({mx + 1, my + 2});
}
if(!check_wall(mx + 2, my + 1, "n")){
    maze[mx + 2][my + 1] = 1;q.push({mx + 2, my + 1});
}
if(!check_wall(mx + 2, my, "n")){
    maze[mx + 2][my] = 1;q.push({mx + 2, my});
}
if(!check_wall(mx + 1, my - 1, "e")){
    maze[mx + 1][my - 1] = 1;q.push({mx + 1, my - 1});
}
if(!check_wall(mx, my - 1, "e")){
    maze[mx][my - 1] = 1; q.push({mx, my - 1});
}
while(!q.empty()){
    int nx, ny;
    nx = q.front().first;
    ny = q.front().second;
    q.pop();
    if(!check_wall(nx + 1, ny, "n") && nx + 1 < 17 && maze[nx + 1][ny] == 0){ // down
        q.push({nx + 1, ny});
        maze[nx + 1][ny] = maze[nx][ny] + 1;
    }
    if(!check_wall(nx, ny - 1, "e") && ny - 1 >= 1 && maze[nx][ny - 1] == 0){ // left
        q.push({nx, ny - 1});
        maze[nx][ny - 1] = maze[nx][ny] + 1;
    }
    if(nx - 1 >= 1 && maze[nx - 1][ny] == 0 && !check_wall(nx - 1, ny, "s")){ // up
        q.push({nx - 1, ny});
        maze[nx - 1][ny] = maze[nx][ny] + 1;
    }
    if(ny + 1 < 17 && maze[nx][ny + 1] == 0 && !check_wall(nx, ny + 1, "w")){ // right
        q.push({nx, ny + 1});
        maze[nx][ny + 1] = maze[nx][ny] + 1;
    }
}
maze[mx][my] = maze[mx + 1][my] = maze[mx + 1][my + 1] = maze[mx][my + 1] = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
log("Running...");
API::setColor(0, 0, 'G');
API::setText(0, 0, "Start");
int d = 1;
int mx = 16, my = 1;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> maze(18,std::vector<int>(18, 0));

while (true) {
    char str[1000];
    sprintf(str, "%d", mx);
    log(str);
    if(d < 1)
        d = 3;
    if(d > 4)
        d = 1;
    mouse_way(d);
    if(API::wallFront()) mark_wall(mx, my, wall_f);
    if(API::wallLeft()) mark_wall(mx, my, wall_l);
    if(API::wallRight()) mark_wall(mx, my, wall_r);
    bfs(maze, 8, 8);
    
    if(direct_mouse[d] == "n"){
        if(maze[mx][my + 1] <= maze[mx][my] && !check_wall(mx, my, "e")  && my + 1 < 17){
            my += 1;
            API::turnRight();
            API::moveForward();
            d++;

        }
        else if(maze[mx][my - 1] <= maze[mx][my] && !check_wall(mx, my, "w")  && my - 1 >= 1){
            my -= 1;
            API::turnLeft();
            API::moveForward();
            d--;
        }
        else if(maze[mx - 1][my] <= maze[mx][my] && !check_wall(mx, my, "n")  && mx - 1 >= 1){
            mx -= 1;
            API:: moveForward();
        }
        else {
            API::turnLeft();
            API::turnLeft();
            d -= 2;
        }
    }
    else if(direct_mouse[d] == "e"){
        if(maze[mx + 1][my] <= maze[mx][my] && !check_wall(mx, my, "s")  && mx + 1 < 17){
            mx += 1;
            API::turnRight();
            API::moveForward();
            d++;
        }
        else if(maze[mx - 1][my] <= maze[mx][my] && !check_wall(mx, my, "n")  && mx - 1 >= 1){
            mx -= 1;
            API::turnLeft();
            API::moveForward();
            d--;
        }
        else if(maze[mx][my + 1] <= maze[mx][my] && !check_wall(mx, my, "e")  && my + 1 < 17){
            my += 1;
            API::moveForward();
        }
        else{
            API::turnLeft();
            API::turnLeft();
            d -= 2;
        }
    }
    else if(direct_mouse[d] == "s"){
        if(maze[mx][my - 1] <= maze[mx][my] && !check_wall(mx, my, "w")  && my - 1 >= 1){
            my -= 1;
            API::turnRight();
            API::moveForward();
            d++;
        }
        else if(maze[mx][my + 1] <= maze[mx][my] && !check_wall(mx, my, "e")  && my + 1 < 17){
            my += 1;
            API::turnLeft();
            API::moveForward();
            d--;
        }
        else if(maze[mx + 1][my] <= maze[mx][my] && !check_wall(mx, my, "s")  && mx + 1 < 17){
            mx += 1;
            API::moveForward();
        }
        else{
            API::turnLeft();
            API::turnLeft();
            d -= 2;
        }
   
    }
    else if(direct_mouse[d] == "w"){
        if(maze[mx - 1][my] <= maze[mx][my] && !check_wall(mx, my, "n")  && mx - 1 >= 1){
            mx -= 1;
            API::turnRight();
            API::moveForward();
            d++;
        }
        else if(maze[mx + 1][my] <= maze[mx][my] && !check_wall(mx, my, "s")  && mx + 1 < 17){
            mx += 1;
            API::turnLeft();
            API::moveForward();
            d--;
        }
        else if(maze[mx][my - 1] <= maze[mx][my] && !check_wall(mx, my, "w") && my - 1 >= 1){
            my -= 1;
            API::moveForward();
        }
        else{
            API::turnLeft();
            API::turnLeft();
            d -= 2;
        }
    }
   /*  for (const auto& row : maze) {
        std::string st = "";
        for (int cell : row) {
            sprintf(str, "%d", cell);
            st = st + str + " ";
        }
        log(st);
    } */
    bfs(maze, 8, 8);
    for(int i = 0; i < e; i++){
        std::string st; 
        sprintf(str, "%d", north_wall[i].first);
        st = st + str;
        sprintf(str, "%d", north_wall[i].second);
        st = st + " " + str;
        log(st);
    }
    log(".......");
    
}
}
```